# hibernate criteria query for one to many relationship with error when selecting children values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lazy-initialization

I have an error when selecting the children values of the installer entity which name it infoRges

installer entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "installer")
    public class Installer implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<InfoRge> infoRges;

    @Column(name = "enterprise_name", length = 50)
    private String name;
    //with getter and setter

    }
```

InstallerListDto class :

```
private Set<InfoRge> infoRges;
private string name;
constructor(Long id, Set<InfoRge> infoRges, String name);
//setters and getters
```

criteria query for selecting list of infoRge :

```
    // Creating the criteria builder
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // Creating the query from Installer Class
    CriteriaQuery<InstallerListDto> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(InstallerListDto.class);

    Root<Installer> from = criteriaQuery.from(Installer.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(cb.construct(InstallerListDto.class, from.get("id"),
                                          from.get("infoRges"),
                                          from.get("name")));
```

error messages :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. as col_5_0_, installer0_.enterprise_name as col_6_0_ from installer installer0' at line 1
```

Comment: The construct of the criteria query needs to be constructed to match the required SQL.

Comment: can you explain more what do you mean ?